# ios push notification approved but settings still says "Off" sometimes

Tags: ios, push-notification

I'm testing my app which uses push notifications, and ask for a standard approval during my onboarding process.  I'm running into trouble in that I ask for approval, click Approve, and then go into Settings only to see that Notifications are set to "Off" for the app.  If I run through the onboarding again it will re-ask, and I can approve, and it will still be "Off".  This does not seem to happen with every install I debug, but something causes it here.  I can delete the app inbetween and it doesn't always help, but I can't pinpoint what is causing it.

```
// on a page describing push messaging in the app, clicking continue button prompts for approval and goes to next view
// it's okay if the transition happens before approving, as the prompt stays above until you approve/deny no matter what
-(IBAction)enablePushBtnClick:(id)sender {
    // attempt to register for push notifications (app supports ios >= 8 only)
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }

    [self continueViews];
}
```

Comment: I am experiencing similar problems. It doesn't appear to do it on older devices or iOS 8.4. I have seen it mis-register for a device running iOS 9.3.